# Delete Task VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to zip my source files and delete all the source files and retain the zip file. Can we specify an exclude pattern while deleting files using VSTS Delete task ? 
Below are the filters I mentioned in the delete task content. The below filters doesnt work they still delete the zip file.

content:
!*.zip
 
**

Comment: What is your objective for wanting to do this? There's no reason to delete source code after a build is complete.

Comment: The publish task takes long time to push code when you have lot of files. This is for database deployment . We have 35000 files. So to get around this I zipped source and unzip in drop folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we specify an exclude pattern while deleting files using VSTS Delete task ?

I am afraid we could not specify an exclude pattern while deleting files using VSTS Delete task at this moment. Fortunately, this feature is coming on the way, damccorm commented on the Github:

> Closing since [#9558](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/pull/9558) has merged and should be rolling out soon. Rolling
>   out will take a little while, but it should be out by the end of
>   March.

You can check the details info from here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4936

Besides, if the publish task takes long time to push code when you have lot of files, you could consider to only publish zip file when you use the publish task.

Hope this helps.